# is it possible to call the method base.Persist() while doing the override of the Persist() on a Graph Extended

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm trying to Override the Persist method on a graph extended to remove a validation of the original method but I'm not able to call the `base.Persist()` method that actually saves the data to the DB in my graph extended. This is what I got so far:

1)I've created the graphextended and its Override method

```
public class POReceiptEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<POReceiptEntry>
{
    public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //baseMethod(); base method is commented so the base.Persist() is not actually happening
        //code without the validation I don't want here

        base.Base.Persist(); //if I add this part the code enters in a endless loop
        Base.poLinesSelection.Cache.Clear();
        Base.openOrders.Cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

can someone help me with this.

Comment: can you just add the fieldverifying event and cancel within your persist as needed? Not sure what you are trying to avoid so hard to say but I would stick with calling baseMethod in your example to correctly persist. Figure out how to handle your validate before baseMethod() via cache/events which you can add just for your persist by doing an AddHandler with your event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last example in the following blog post demonstrates how to call PXGraph.Persist() in a PXGraphExtension to avoid the logic in the graph's overridden Persist method.

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/override-static-method.html

As stated in the blog post - this methodology should be avoided unless it is necessary.